# Firebase: Closure in obvserveEventType and observeSingleEventOfType withBlock: Not executing (with assembly)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I cannot figure out why the databaseRef withBlock never executes.

I have already made a working real-time chat app in Swift & everything worked as expected so I'm not totally new at this...

The user logs in on a LoginViewController with Facebook auth and is forwarded to this main view.  The tweets are stored in Firebase database.

When I set the breakpoints and step through this, it jumps down to the second error closure, repeats the error closure twice & then goes into the assembly instructions. (at bottom of post)

I've tried various ways of calling the observeEventType and observeSingleEventOfType (which is what I'd like to do) and the result is always the same here.

I've printed all the objects to console to make sure the user is logged in and with FirebaseAuth.

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase

class MainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
{
    var loggedInUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
    var loggedInUserDetails = AnyObject?()
    @IBOutlet weak var homeTableView: UITableView!

    var tweets = [AnyObject?]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().referenceWithPath("user_profile/\(self.loggedInUser!.uid)")

        print(self.loggedInUser!uid)  // Prints uid
        // get the logged in user -- POINT OF FAILURE
        databaseRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: {(snapshot) in

        //store the logged in user's details
        self.loggedInUserDetails = snapshot

        //get all the tweets by the user
        databaseRef.child("tweets/\(self.loggedInUser!.uid)").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: {(snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in

            self.tweets.append(snapshot)

            self.homeTableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow:0, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)

        }) {(error) in
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }) {(error) in
            print("Error 1")  // never prints
            print(error.localizedDescription)  //never prints
       }
}
```

---

I also noticed when stepping through the assembly instructions with xcode it gets to a cancel callback call.

This is where it starts (line 1)

```
0x10f5b3db8 <+36>: movq   %r12, -0x30(%rbp)
0x10f5b3dbc <+40>: movq   0x1a7a8d(%rip), %rax      ; (void *)0x000000010f762e70: FIRDatabaseReference
0x10f5b3dc3 <+47>: movq   %rax, -0x28(%rbp)
0x10f5b3dc7 <+51>: movq   0x19f39a(%rip), %rsi      ; "observeSingleEventOfType:withBlock:withCancelBlock:"
0x10f5b3dce <+58>: leaq   -0x30(%rbp), %rdi
```

Then after several jumps it executes this instruction:

```
   0x10f5b874e <+291>: movq   0x19ef03(%rip), %rsi      ; "observeChildEventWithHandle:withCallbacks:cancelCallback:"
```

Comment: If the code goes to one of the error closures, you most likely don't have permission to read the data. The `error` will contain information about the exact error (such as what location you're trying to read that you don't have permission to).

Comment: Sorry...I forgot to explain that it never executes the code in the error closure.  I just jumps from error to the final bracket then goes back to error.  Is there another way to find the error?  I didn't see any error-looking comments in the assembly.

Comment: I have checked to confirm the user is logged in (in the code edit above) and it does print out the uid as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't an Xcode issue after all...the problem was the tableView(numberOfRowsInSection) was returning the wrong number of rows & that was messing everything up.

I've learned that Firebase does not always execute things in the order you would expect.

Once I found the problem, I stepped through the debugger and it went into viewDidLoad, hit the observeSingleEvent and then jumped to the end of the closure....just like I thought was the problem.  But then it went to my tableView()->UITableView function and began execution before returning back to the observeSingleEvent that we're trying to get data for.

Almost seems that the Firebase closure is lazily executed.

If I find more out about this topic I'll fix up this answer.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You could be getting an error.

```
// get the logged in user -- POINT OF FAILURE
databaseRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: {(snapshot) in

    //store the logged in user's details
    self.loggedInUserDetails = snapshot

    //get all the tweets by the user
    databaseRef.child("tweets/\(self.loggedInUser!.uid)").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: {(snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in

        self.tweets.append(snapshot)

        self.homeTableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow:0, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)

    }) {(error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}) {(error) in
    print(error.localizedDescription) // maybe permission denied?
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't the error closure at the end catch that and print it to the console?  When stepping through the debugger it goes right past the last bracket in the withBlock

Comment: You have nested observers, but you are only handling the error block for the inner. If the `observeSingleEventOfType` observation were to fail, since you have no error block, nothing would happen.

Comment: Ah...didn't notice that, but there is no error.  This is pretty frustrating...  I've poured over the code with a fine-tooth comb...it's like this one thing decided not to work.   Maybe it's some quirk in xcode..